# Run Javascript on Spawned Window in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension, and one of the behaviors is to spawn a popup window with a specified size and location:

```
url = "https://google.com"
chrome.windows.create(
  {
    'url':    url,
    'type':   'popup',
    'width':  Math.floor(screen.availWidth  / 2),
    'height': Math.floor(screen.availHeight / 2),
    'left':   Math.floor(screen.availWidth  / 2),
    'top':    0
  },
  function(window) {}
);
```

At this point I need to run some Javascript on the spawned page. I understand that I can declare a content script in my manifest that matches `url`, however the url is actually dynamic, and can be pretty much anything.

So, my best guess right now would be to add a content script with matcher `https://*/*`, and through some other means determine that this is the page which was spawned by the extension - either through adding some query param, or through the extension messaging system.

This approach seems kind of hacky, though. Does anyone know of a more 'proper' way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) inside the callback:

```
chrome.windows.create({ /*params*/ }, w => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(w.tabs[0].id, {file: 'content.js'});
});
```

Notes:

- The site or `"<all_urls>"` must be added in `"permissions"` in manifest.json.
- The returned [window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window) is not the JavaScript `window` so it's best to use a different name.

Comment: Awesome. Might be worth pointing out that the path of the file must be relative to the _root_ of the chrome extension. Thanks!

Comment: One follow up question, if you don't mind. I noticed that when I refreshed the spawned page, my script is no longer attached (which makes sense, I guess). Is there a way to store a reference to this page/tab in localStorage? Then I could make a content script matching  `https://*/*` and the page could "look itself up" to determine whether it should inject the "launched page" script. Not sure if there would be a better way to handle it

Comment: You can add a listener for tab updates in the background script and do executeScript again of it's the same tab id. For more info open a new question if needed.

Comment: Oh I see, so tab IDs are global and I don't need the "window ID" as well. Thanks.